# How to get Quartz NET scheduler from services collection to CrystalQuartz

Tags: asp.net-core, quartz.net

I'm trying to use Quartz NET and CrystalQuartz with .NET 5.
I add the scheduler to services collection with `AddQuartz`

How could I get the scheduler from the services collection within?

```
services.AddQuartz(q =>{

...

q.SchedulerId = "MyScheduler ID";

...

})
```

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you need to install `CrystalQuartz.AspNetCore` NuGet package to the target project.

As a next step, you need to hook CrystalQuartz middleware into your ASP.NET Core environment. It should be done by calling `UseCrystalQuartz` extension method at the moment of pipeline initialization. The generic syntax for panel configuration looks like this:

```
 app.UseCrystalQuartz(() => scheduler, options);
```

scheduler is your IScheduler (local or remote).

You should already have an `IScheduler` object instance so you can pass a `Func` pointing to it to the configuration extension method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    IScheduler scheduler = CreateScheduler();
    app.UseCrystalQuartz(() => scheduler);

    // ...
}

// this method is just a sample of scheduler initialization
private IScheduler CreateScheduler()
{
    var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;

    // construct job info
    var jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
        .WithIdentity("myJob")
        .StoreDurably()
        .Build();

    // fire every minute
    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("myTrigger")
        .StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(1).RepeatForever())
        .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

    scheduler.Start();

    return scheduler;
}
```

Comment: Can't I use CrystalQuartz with AddQuartz() function?